# Python regular expression; match on the last instance

Tags: python, regex

I have a bunch of html I am trying to deal with. I want to delete the last half tag that I have. Basically I am starting with:

```
</div></div><div class="_3o-d" id="education
```

and want to end with:

```
</div></div>
```

I tried:

```
workSection = re.split('<.*?$',workSection)[0]
```

but this matches the first '<' and leaves me with an empty string. Is there a way to just match the last instance? Or to somehow start from the end?

I am also aware that splitting and then taking the first option may not be the best way of doing this, and am prepared to take a beating for it now.

Comment: Obligatory http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: why are you trying to do that? depending on what you hope to accomplish there is probably a better way

Comment: @ChristianTernus: more than mandatory!! ;)

Comment: Basically, I am just trying to remove all the HTML, but first I wanted to do some splits on some specific tags. This left a couple of half tags.

Comment: The problem with using a parser is that this HTML appears to be invalid

Comment: Ok it's only invalid because you are using regex to _break_ it then. Save yourself future headcaches and use a proper parser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `[^<]` instead of the `.`

```
>>> re.split('<[^<]*$', '</div></div><div class="_3o-d" id="education')
['</div></div>', '']
```